# Assembly: compile a COM program

Tags: assembly, tasm

Can COM program be 32 bit?

How can I compile COM program?
I have TLINK32 and TASM32.

```
tasm32 \t alex_7.asm
pause
tlink32 alex_7.obj 
pause
td32 main.exe
```

I ve got following error:

```
Fatal: 16 bit segments not supported in module alex_7.asm
```

I have DOSBOX and I'am running Windows 7 x64

I got same when I try to compile my program inside DOSBOX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [.com files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file) are small (max. 64kb) DOS/16-bit-era executable files, with a segmented memory model. In MASM, you'd use `.MODEL TINY`, `ORG 100h` and fit everything into the code segment. As far as I know, there are no 32-bit .com files.

Answer (score 0):

COM objects can most definitely be 32 bit, the problem you're having is that you're using 16bit code on a 64 bit system. You can only run 32bit and 64bit programs under a 64 bit system (but you can't mix them up together under most scenarios).

Comment: Oh. Oops. I don't think COM files can be anything but 16-bit.

Comment: I tried to compile my program using tasm and tlink (16 bit).
tlink says `no stack`

Comment: @Fantomas: Then the term you are looking for is PE-Executable.